# Zusammensetzung von Verb auf -en und Substantiv: Schneidmaschine oder Schneidemaschine?

Tags: compound

*Schneidemaschine* scheint viel geläufiger zu sein als *Schneidmaschine*, und der Duden und das DWDS kennen nur die erste Schreibung.
Es klingt für mich aber falsch oder zumindest ungelenk.

Es heißt ja auch nicht Mähemaschine, sondern Mähmaschine; nicht Sehehilfe, sondern Sehhilfe; nicht Essegeschirr, sondern Essgeschirr.

Bei Worten, die aus einem auf -en endenden Verb und einem Substantiv bestehen, wird das letzte *e* des Verbs gestrichen, sagt mir mein Sprachgefühl.

Aber gibt es dazu eine Regel oder ist es einem freigestellt?

edit:
Gerade ist mir aufgefallen, dass sich einige andere Wörter ähnlich bilden wie *Schneidemaschine*: Nachsend**e**auftrag, Lad**e**hemmung etc.

Hat es etwas mit dem *d* vor der Verbendung -en zu tun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sprachwissenschaftler kennen Fügelaute, also Laute, die zwischen Wörter, die zusammengefügt werden, eingeschoben werden, oft aus Gründen der Aussprechbarkeit. Dies übrigens in vielen Sprachen.

Sehr prominent im Deutschen das "o" im Wahl-o-mat. Ein Streitobjekt die Lok-o-motive. Man denke aber auch an Pferd-e-kutsche, Esel-s-brücke, Dackel-ø-blick (mit Nullmorphem - aber warum heißt es eigentlich nicht Dackel-s-blick?), Hund-e-kuchen, Katze-n-schwanz.

Es gibt keine rechte Regel zu Numerus oder Kasus bei solchen Bildungen, eher hängt das Vokal- oder Konsonanteneinfügen von Aussprachebequemlichkeiten ab, scheint mir.

Wer sagt, meistens spiele hier ein Plural mit (Pferde-kutsche? Hunde-kuchen?), der erkläre mir den Pferd-e-schwanz, da kein Pferd zwei Schwänze und kein Schwanz zwei Pferde hat, sowie maus-e-tot - nota bene nicht mäuse-tot.

Vorschlag darum: Man könnte das "e" in Schneid-e-maschine als solchen Fügevokal interpretieren.

Kantapper sind Fälle, wo mehrere Formen parallel in den Wald hinein rollen:

> Pfann-ø-kuchen
>
> Pfann-e-kuchen
>
> Pfann-en-kuchen

Comment: Interessant, vielen Dank! Also hat das auch nichts damit zu tun, dass hier Verb und Substantiv verbunden werden (In deinen Beispielen sind es ausnahmslos Substantive)? Oder damit, ob der letzte Konsonant vor der Endung ein Plosiv ist, oder aspiriert, oder sonst eine Eigenschaft aufweist?

Comment: @philipp   Ich würde für die Erklärung, die ich vorgeschlagen habe, nicht beanspruchen, dass sie die einzige mögliche ist. Insbesondere erklärt sie ja auch nicht, wieso ein bestimmter Laut eingesetzt wird. Vielleicht lassen sich bei genauer Beobachtungen noch bestimmte Regelhaftigkeiten im System der Sprache entdecken. Man sollte dabei nur nicht vergessen, dass natürliche Sprachen ja nicht von Ingenieuren konstruiert werden, sondern von selbst entstehen und sich entwickeln und dass "Regeln", die man analysiertend darin sieht, stets nur (eventuell solide) Theorien sind.